# Network die after a while

Tags: networking

I have an odd problem with a wired connection on 16.04.3. It seems different from similar problems found here.

When I start my ubuntu server, it works fine but after a short time it disconnects from network, I can only restart it. The more I work, for example big file transfer, the faster it stop working. Tipically few minutes.

The only hint I have is: internet stops first. I mean: from linux box, if I ping something like www.google.com it works, at beginning. After few minutes it cannot resolve names.

Here some data:

```
 root@Tortuga:/var/log# ifconfig enp37s0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr
 88:d7:f6:7d:c9:90
           inet addr:192.168.1.42  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
           inet6 addr: fe80::8ad7:f6ff:fe7d:c990/64 Scope:Link
           UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
           RX packets:2133 errors:0 dropped:6 overruns:0 frame:0
           TX packets:1914 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
           collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
           RX bytes:174207 (174.2 KB)  TX bytes:719226 (719.2 KB)
```

Interfaces:

```
root@Tortuga:/etc/network# cat interfaces
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto enp37s0
iface enp37s0 inet static
address 192.168.1.42
gateway 192.168.1.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
dns-nameservers 8.8.4.4 208.67.222.222
```

Linux version:

```
root@Tortuga:/var/log# cat /etc/debian_version
stretch/sid
```

How can I troubleshoot this? What can I search in syslog (or where)?

===== Edit =====
Still facing the problem, now I have errors like:

> Dec  3 20:27:32 Tortuga kernel: [ 2037.734502] AMD-Vi: Event logged
>   [IO_PAGE_FAULT device=25:00.0 domain=0x0001 address=0x0000000006380000
>   flags=0x0050] Dec  3 20:27:48 Tortuga kernel: [ 2053.145060] r8169
>   0000:25:00.0 enp37s0: link up Dec  3 20:28:00 Tortuga kernel: [
>   2065.568824] AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT device=25:00.0 domain=0x0001 address=0x0000000006380000 flags=0x0050] Dec  3 20:29:18
>   Tortuga kernel: [ 2143.146459] r8169 0000:25:00.0 enp37s0: link up

Comment: Please, do not use root when it is not really necessary.  Use `sudo` instead (refer to the many discussions about it)

Comment: For how long you are facing this problem? Seems driver compatibility issue to me.

Comment: @ArpitAgarwal, since installation few days ago.

Comment: Then you should try some other distro

Comment: Have you seen something in the `/var/log/syslog` log file around the problem? are you using the HWE kernel (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack)? What is the make/model of your network adapter?